# How to deal with textile strike-through

Tags: zend-framework, markup, textile

```
south-west to north-east
```

Will render: "south<del>west to north</del>east" using Textile.

I'm expecting to get: "south-west to north-east"

Isn't there a way to handle these kind of situations? Is that the intended behavior? (if so, that's really bad...)

For information, I'm using Zend Frameworks Textile parser class.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like you have stumbled upon a known bug.

```
south-west to north-east
```

Should render as you expect it to. With a space before it `-` is Textile markup for `<del></del>` tags.

```
south -west to north- east
```

Should give the result you are getting.

You can see what your markup should produce here http://textile.thresholdstate.com/

It seems that this class is not useable at the moment according to this issue http://framework.zend.com/issues/browse/ZF-9797

I've never used it, but I would suggest you try this class http://textile.thresholdstate.com/file_download/1/textile-2.0.0.zip

Comment: Thank you, I'll use the official library instead.